# Create the missing transaction log file

Tags: sql

I've got 10 log files that must restore inside a database but 1 of them is missing. Is there a way inside the database to create the missing log file again and restore it on the backup database, without do the full backup again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't make specific transaction log file

Transaction log backups are required to provide a more continuous data stream, to allow more complete recovery from a case of inadvertent data loss and to also provide vital transactional information, not found in regular database backups

Transaction log backups don’t only provide successful auditing and recovery, but also enable the backed up log records to be removed from the online transaction log file. The new transactions overwrite the old ones, thus preventing the transaction log file from growing. If you do not back up the transaction log frequently enough, it can become huge and affect the database performance

You need to ensure that you have a transaction log chain. A log chain is a continuous sequence of transaction log backups. It starts with a full database backup followed by all subsequent log backups up through the recovery/auditing point

A log chain enables to audit/recover/rollback the transactions quicker using just several transaction log backup files instead of a single online transaction log which can be multiple times bigger than all transaction log backups used

Your chain must remain unbroken, if it becomes broken, only the transactions in the logs up to the last backup before the missing one can be shown